# Access Kubernetes API with kubectl failed after enabling RBAC

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I'm trying to enable RBAC on my cluster and iadded those following line to the kube-apiserver.yml :

```
- --authorization-mode=RBAC
- --runtime-config=rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
- --authorization-rbac-super-user=admin
```

and i did systemctl restart kubelet ; 
the apiserver starts successfully but i'm not able to run kubectl command and i got this error :

```
kubectl get po 
Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "kubectl" cannot list pods in the namespace "default"
```

where am I going wrong or i should create some roles to the kubectl user ?  if so how that possible

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "kubectl" cannot list pods in the namespace "default"
> ```

You are using user `kubectl` to access cluster by `kubectl` utility, but you set `--authorization-rbac-super-user=admin`, which means your super-user is `admin`.

To fix the issue, launch kube-apiserver with superuser "kubectl" instead of "admin."

Just update the value of the option: `--authorization-rbac-super-user=kubectl`.

Comment: You can try to create a Role with full access to all resources, RoleBinding to attach that Role to the `kubectl` user and then enable RBAC. [Here](https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-rbac-in-your-kubernetes-cluster/) is the good instruction about how to do it.

Comment: yes but this is a lit bit complicated, i sould disable RBAC then create a clusterrole for kubectl and then enable RBAC, there is no clean and simple method to do that, otherwise do u know if there is some option in order to run kubefed on a NON RBAC deployment ?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no simple method for do that.You can try to use kubefed without RBAC, but it is not recommend. Here is the quote from the [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/federation/set-up-cluster-federation-kubefed/#choosing-a-host-cluster): "If you wish to enable basic authentication or token authentication for debugging purposes, you can enable them by passing the --apiserver-enable-basic-auth flag or the --apiserver-enable-token-auth flag."

Answer (score 0):

Old question but for google searchers, you can use the insecure port:

> If your API server runs with the insecure port enabled (--insecure-port), you can also make API calls via that port, which does not enforce authentication or authorization.

Source: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#privilege-escalation-prevention-and-bootstrapping

So add `--insecure-port=8080` to your kube-apiserver options and then restart it.

Then run:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding kubectl-cluster-admin-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin --user=kubectl
```

Then turn the insecure-port off.